# Android Studio - Generating a signed bundle leaves out local json file

Tags: android-studio, android-resources, android-assets

I have a local json file which is critical to the app. The file is around 28mbs in size. I have it stored under res>raw. However, when I generate a signed bundle from release variant, the build is only 4 mbs. If I generate a signed bundle from debug, it's 41 mbs and does include the json file.

I've tried using source sets but no effect. This is what my app structure looks like.

[image: This is what my app structure looks like]

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found out that the maximum size of a raw file is 1023kb. Anything more than that and you're left with unexpected behaviour. I fixed it by breaking the given json file (~28mb) into 30 small json files.